# Can anyone please explain to me the following

Tags: c, pointers, casting

Could anyone explain to me what happens during the runtime of the following snippet and why does it print 33?
Thanks,

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    int* p = (int*)17;
    printf("%d\n", (int)(long)(p+4));
}
```

Comment: Everything about this code is undefined behaviour as far as I can tell. It could print *anything*.

Comment: @tadman not really ...

Comment: Well, only the `p+4` part.

Comment: Converting integers to pointers is "implementation defined" and so is the arithmetic on the pointer, the system might have a hidden device at that fixed address :)

Answer (score 6):

`p` is a pointer to an `int`, or to some `int`s.

You initialize it to point to address 17.  (This is a big problem for a couple of reasons, which we'll get to.)

You then add 4 to it.  Evidently, `sizeof(int)` on your machine is 4, that is, an `int` takes up 4 bytes (32 bits).  When you add 4 to an `int` pointer, the compiler knows you want to make it point 4 `int`'s worth farther on, so the compiler adds 4 × 4 = 16 to the address.  Now `p` points at address 33.

Then you "cast" (convert) `p` from a pointer to a `long`.  So now, instead of a pointer to address 33, it's just the number 33.

Then you cast it again, from `long` to `int`.  This basically converts it from 33 to 33.  (If type `long` on your machine is bigger than 4 bytes, this conversion might have involved converting from, say, a 64-bit value 33 to the 32-bit value 33, that is, from `0x0000000000000021` to `0x00000021`.)

Then you print that last `int` value out, using `%d`.  So you see the number 33.

Now, normally, saying something like

```
int* p = (int*)17;
```

is a bad idea, because you have a pointer with a value that probably can't be used.  Normally, one thing you do with pointers is to manipulate the values that they point to.  But if you were to say

```
printf("value pointed to by p is %d\n", *p);
```

you would end up trying to fetch an `int` value from address 17 in memory.  But (a) you probably don't have permission to read from address 17, and (b) 17 is not a multiple of 4, so your processor might not even be willing to try to fetch an `int` from there even if you did have permission.  So this code would almost certainly crash.

But since in your code, you never actually try to do anything with the `int` hypothetically pointed to by `p` (neither before nor after you add 4 to it), your code will probably -- and just barely -- seem to "work".

On the one hand this is bad, nonportable, barely-defined if not outright undefined, code.  But then again, it's probably not intended to be practical (clearly no one would run it to get any actual work done).  So if all we take away from it is a lesson in how pointer arithmetic works (in particular, how it's automatically scaled by the compiler based on the size of the pointed-to objects), perhaps we don't have to spend too much time belaboring its many uglinesses and imperfections.  (There's a little quibble going on down in the comment thread as to whether the code is *undefined* or merely *implementation-defined*, but as long as you take care not to write code like this for real, you don't necessarily have to worry about the distinction.)

If you want to learn more or less the same lesson about pointer arithmetic, but using a much more reasonable and mostly-portable program, try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

int main()
{
    int *p = &a[3];
    printf("p is %p and points to %d\n", p, *p);
    printf("p+4 is %p and points to %d\n", p+4, *(p+4));
}
```

Here, instead of stuffing an artificial value like 17 into `p`, we're initializing it to point into an actual array, as pointers are intended to.  And instead of converting the pointer value to `int` and printing it with `%d`, we're printing it using `%p`, which is designed to print pointers.

On my machine, this program prints

```
p is 0x10f47a02c and points to 3
p+4 is 0x10f47a03c and points to 7
```

As you can see, the pointer values are not easily-digestible little numbers like 17 and 33, and my machine has chosen to print them in hexadecimal.  Nevertheless, it's easy to verify that `0x10f47a03c` - `0x10f47a02c` is `0x10`, or 16.  We added 4, meaning "make it point to the 4th `int` past where it points now", and the compiler added 16.

[Footnote.  I said this was "mostly portable".  To make it perfectly portable, you'd have to change the `printf` calls to

```
    printf("p is %p and points to %d\n", (void *)p, *p);
    printf("p+4 is %p and points to %d\n", (void *)(p+4), *(p+4));
```

Strictly speaking, `%p` is only defined to print generic pointers to `void`, not arbitrary other pointer types.  So, strictly speaking, we need those `(void *)` casts, to convert the pointer values into the correct pointer type for printing.]

Comment: Patience, @EugeneSh., patience.  I was still editing.

Comment: @EugeneSh. AFAIK, a pointer not pointing to an object, or 1 behind the end of an object is **invalid**, but that doesn't make the behavior of this code (which never dereferences the pointer) undefined, IMHO. Implementation defined, of course...

Comment: As far as I understand, the result of the pointer arithmetic operation is UB: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p8 Not clear though what happens if the pointer operand is invalid by itself.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: C 2011 6.5.6 8 defines addition with a pointer. It specifies the result for certain cases, none of which apply here, and then says “… otherwise, the behavior is undefined.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil nope, the exact wording is "*If both the pointer
operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last
element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the
behavior is undefined.*" -- so UB only if the *pointer overflows(?)* -- anyways, this refers to this sentence only, indicated by the semicolon.

Comment: @EricPostpischil the text doesn't say anything about the result of these operations on an already invalid pointer. OP's code is not "well-defined", but it doesn't invoke UB either.

Comment: @EricPostpischil that's a possible interpretation, I read it differently -- this whole sentence only applies to pointers pointing to some array objects. C explicitly allows converting an integer to a pointer, which will be either *invalid* or point to some object of the outside world (which requires implementation and platform knowledge) and this paragraph tells exactly nothing about what happens when doing arithmetics on such pointers.

Comment: Of course, in any case, the results of OPs code are unpredictable -- it's not useful ...

Comment: @FelixPalmen: The pointer operand and the result do not both point to elements of the same array or one past it. Therefore, the condition is not satised, so the “otherwise” applies. Understanding the background for pointers in C may help interpret this paragraph. C supports a variety of address spaces, not just flat address spaces. In some of these, oointer arithmetic must be done in the context of allocated segments of memory. Implementing pointer arithmetic requires more than just a scaling by size and an addition. So the C standard makes pointer arithmetic not in an array undefined.

Comment: @EricPostpischil on the contrary, C **only** supports a single address space. Everything else is done using extensions/attributes (like e.g. on AVR's harvard architecture, or in the old IBM-PC segmented scheme with "far"). There might be holes and any strange things, so the paragraphs for conversion to and from integers (6.3.2.3 p5,6) are written in a way to allow undefined behavior (by trap representations, overflows, anything), but there's no distinction possible between **different** address spaces.

Comment: @FelixPalmen The reason pointer arithmetic is explicitly defined only on pointers within the same array is to admit the possibility that two different arrays might be in two different memory segments.  I call that supporting non-flat address spaces!  If `p` and `q` point into different arrays, computing `p-q` makes about as much sense as asking "How many houses are there between 123 Main St. and 456 First Ave.?"  (And the answer is probably *not* the as-the-crow-flies or Pythagorean distance, much less the "Manhattan distance" :-) .)

Comment: @SteveSummit I was opposing the "variety of address spaces" -- but maybe this wasn't meant as "multiple at once".

Comment: @SteveSummit and yes, of course, there are multiple *opportunities* for UB in the code of this question. But I don't see anything definitely marking it as UB. It's allowed to convert any integer to a pointer, you could directly end up with a trap representation, but if you don't, there also isn't any text explicitly forbidding to do arithmetics here. In fact, it **must** be allowed (in an implementation-defined manner) for  some typical access to memory-mapped registers in some architectures.

Comment: Converting integers to pointers and back is "implementation defined". If the platform decides it has an object that is large enough at that address, the arithmetic `p+4` is also valid. The system might have a hidden device at that fixed address :) In short, this program is not portable.

Comment: @JensGustedt Your assertion about `p+4` needs a better justification than just your rep :) The whole hardware register thing is a moot point. But you still able to define these in a well defined way. For instance, calculate offsets when the address is integer and then cast it to a pointer.

Comment: @EugeneSh. That arithmetic is defined if `p` is a valid pointer to an object and if that object has at least  `sizeof(int[3])` bytes. If the system has an object at "address" `17` that is large enough this is fine. Observe the multiple use of the term *if* in these assertions.

Comment: @JensGustedt The "object" in terms of C is not the "system's" object, but a C object. Yes, if the same program have defined an object at address 17, then yes, it is defined.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, "object" in terms of C can be a "system's" object. The very definition in the C standard for *object* says: *region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values*. If the platform decides that `17` is valid in the sense that I indicated, this is fine.

Comment: @JensGustedt But the system cannot decide it. Let's switch to practical. Consider an ARM Cortex-A(whatever) core - based microprocessor with a bunch of vendor-specific memory mapped registers around. The compiler you would use for it is a generic ARM compiler, which is unaware of these vendor-specific stuff. How can it ever know that 0x17 is the address of a whatever Fan controller register?

Comment: @FelixPalmen: My statement that C (meaning the C standard) supports a “variety of address spaces“ does not mean it supports multiple address spaces in a single implementation simultaneously. It means the standard supports many implementations which have, among them, various address spaces, some of them which are complicated and not flat and for which the standard cannot (and does not) define pointer arithmetic with pointers converted from arbitrary integers. The standard defines pointer arithmetic only for those cases it requires implementations to support: within arrays.

Comment: @Eric then I read this wrong. Of course, supporting "non-flat" address spaces requires the *possibility* of undefined results with pointer arithmetics. OTOH, I don't see how C could **fully** support something like this (braindead) IBM PC segmented memory model without any extensions. Anyways, you can interpret this whole paragraph in different ways and if you interpret it as strict as you do, it would make typical (implementation-defined) use-cases of low-level C impossible...

Comment: @EugeneSh. you could make endless arguments here, but as Jens writes "*"object" in terms of C can be a "system's" object*"" <- that's definitely one *intention*, to make such use-cases possible. They can't be well-defined, because they heavily depend on the machine, but they aren't undefined either. The paragprah about the results of pointer arithmetics can be understood in different ways, what's probably *meant* is to not tell anything about pointers "to the environment" or whatever :o IMHO, there's some **clear** statement missing here [...]

Comment: @EugeneSh.   [...] like e.g. "if the pointer is the implementation-defined result of a conversion from an integer type, the result of the arithmetic operation is implementation-defined as well, and may be undefined" (not perfectly worded, but it would describe the reality of existing implementations quite well)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the result of `33` tells me your machine uses `int` with `sizeof(int) == 4` (4 bytes).

Converting an integer to a pointer is allowed, with implementation-defined results. That's what this line does:

```
int* p = (int*)17;
```

now it's a pointer to int, and `p+4` will add 4 times the size of an `int` to the pointer. `17 + 4*4` is `33`.

Your second line

```
printf("%d\n", (int)(long)(p+4));
```

converts this pointer to a `long`, only to convert it to an `int` immediately afterwards. The conversion to `long` doesn't serve any purpose here.

The result of all this is *implementation defined*, as you **will** get different results on other machines. There's no guarantee that `17` is a valid value for a pointer, so the conversion could give you a different value.

But assuming `17` is a valid value for a pointer and `int` on your machine has a size of `4`, the result is `33`.